# SslStream without certificate

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl, tcp

I am designing a system in a client server architecture - TCP based. There is a requirement that all the messages between the server & client should be encrypted. So I am thinking of using `SslStream` class in .NET Framework.

From SslStream MSDN, my understanding is that we need to use Client & server certificates to make a proper channel & communicate.

I don't want to use any certificate specific to particular machine(client) or server. I Just wanted to have a common key between the system.

Is there any possibility to use the SSL stream without certificates??

Comment: OpenSSL supports cert less connections but you need to configure it to use something like Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst not required by the TLS spec, the use of the .NET `SslStream` implementation requires that the server has a certificate (and its associated private key). This allows any client to confirm that it is communicating with the server it expects to be. Optionally, clients can also be authenticated by having them provide a client certificate to the server. So, if you want to use `SslStream`, you're at a minimum going to have to create a certificate for the server, because that is how this particular implementation works.

If you don't wish to use certificates at all, then there are other options. E.g. if you are planning on using your application within a Windows domain, and both client/server are Windows based, you may be able to use `NegotiateStream` instead. This also supports encryption/authentication, but does not use certificates, and will additionally allow you to identify the user on the other side of the connection.

Comment: That is not true. TLS Clearly defines in it's spec ciphers that are "anon" meaning no certificate. If you use ECDHE or DHE then the keys can be exchanged securely without a certificate to encrypt them.

Comment: @Drawaes You are correct, however it does not seem possible to use anonymous key exchange modes via .NET's `SslStream` (according to the documentation on the `AuthenticateAsServer()` method, the certificate argument is mandatory). I have updated my answer accordingly.